# Open file dialog with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, click, double-click

I try to open file dialog box in javascript. I tried with next code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#lblupload").click(function () {

                $("#upload").trigger('click');
            });

            $("#upload").change(function () {
                $("#div").css("display", "block");
            });
        });


    </script>

  <asp:Label ID="lblupload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >UPLOAD</asp:Label>

        <asp:FileUpload ID="upload" runat="server" />



        <div id="div" style="display:none;">
           Are you sure ... ?
               <asp:Button ID="btn_upload" runat="server" OnClick="btn_upload_Click" Text="yes" />

        </div>
```

Works great in all browsers except IE. 
In IE, single click on button *btn_upload* not working only double click.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try focus() ?

Answer (score 0):

What errors are you seeing in your log? I just tried this example and it worked right back to IE 7:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblupload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >UPLOAD</asp:Label>

<asp:FileUpload ID="upload" runat="server" />    

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#lblupload').on('click', function () {
            $('#upload').trigger('click');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't get any error message. Button works only with double click. Nothing happens on single click.

Comment: does it fail in all versions of ie for you? is there any other code on the page?